# Python, How to get file mimetype from the system?

Tags: python, mime-types

I have a file that I know for development is opml markup, but that file has no extension, because naturally, a file extension doesn't define a file anyway. On ubuntu the `mimetype` command correctly identifies the file:

```
$ mimetype myfile 
myfile: text/x-opml+xml
```

Python, as best as I can tell, does not do any equivalent mimetype guessing, but rather is class with a single lookup table that dumbly maps file extensions to mimetypes. Even calling their mimtyles read method on the file beforehand, which I would expect to yeild an object of greater information, just returns None, and doesn't influence the MimeTypes object for future calls.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

PATH = 'myfile'

from mimetypes import mimetypes

mimetypes = MimeTypes()
print(PATH)
print(mimetypes.read(PATH))
print(mimetypes.guess_type(PATH))
```

Call output:

```
$ python2 ./myscript.py 
myfile
None
(None, None)
```

---

So I was considering using a subprocess to call the system's mimetype identifier for the file, but I was really hoping to keep this cross-platform/portable. Any ideas?

Comment: @dawg Thanks for linking something close; however the libmagic does not identify `opml`, or rather it uselessly identifies it as `text/plain`. That's why I asked for something closer to a system pass-though to what the actual `mimetype` command does.

Comment: Looked up the `mimetype` command and found it comes from a perl library: [`libfile-mimeinfo-perl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libfile-mimeinfo-perl)

Comment: This has no sense, I cannot answer you formally. But in short, there is no easy solution to that. You will have to rewrite mimetype command in Python. As it is Perl you will not have too much trouble. Use your logic to parse first X bytes of a file and get the list mapping headers to types from the Perl script. I didn't find it anywhere else.